# SQL Query vs Pandas Filter or other more efficient alternative

Tags: sql, pandas, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I have a large database and a number of subjects (40000).
For each subject_id, I am currently running a SQL Query like this:

```
query = """
      SELECT *
      FROM `database.{}.{}`
      WHERE subject_id={} AND itemid={}
      """.format(dataset_name, table_name, subject_id, itemid)
```

The number of rows with subject_id in the database = subject_id that is used as a parameter are much less than the number of rows in the database (approx 1/40000 of course). The database is on BigQuery and I am using Google Colab for the query.

Is it more efficient to do this instead where I use several subject_ids as parameters and filter the dataframe?

```
query = """
      SELECT *
      FROM `database.{}.{}`
      WHERE subject_id in ({}) AND itemid={}
      """.format(dataset_name, table_name, ",".join([str(sid) for sid in subject_ids]), itemid)

    try:
      item_data1 = run_query(query)
      if len(item_data1) != 0:
        for subject_id in subject_ids:
          item_data = item_data1[item_data1['subject_id'] == subject_id]
```

Is there a better way to do this so that it is more efficient?

Comment: my guess would be that hitting the database once instead of 40,000 times will be faster/cheaper, but you can try timing both approaches. I don't think pandas will be the bottleneck

Comment: Definitely the `in  ({...})` version will be faster, by a looong stretch. Also, your query is highly susceptible to SQL injection attack. Find a way to parameterize it probably.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you please link me something to read up on to/explain how I would avoid a SQL injection attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CodeDifferent mentioned in comments:

Definitely the in  `({...})` version will be faster, by a looong stretch. Also, your query is highly susceptible to *SQL injection attack*. Find a way to parameterize it probably.

You may refer to this [Parameterized queries in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) documentation since this helps prevent *SQL injection* when queries are constructed using user input.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.